# Количество повторений в слове Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например для слова `'abab'` количество повторений 3: `'a' 'b' 'ab'` , но
код который я написал ищет повторы только по буквам. Как сделать так чтобы он искал все повторы в строке

```
a=input()
m=[] 
def duplicate_count(text):
    d=len(text)
    s=0
    for h in range(d):
        f=[]
        for i in range(h):
            f.append(text[i])
            if text[i].lower() in text[i+1:].lower() and text[i].lower() not in m:
                m.append(text[i].lower())
                s+=1
    return s
print(duplicate_count(a))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
a = input('Введите строку: ')

def duplicate_count(text):
    d = {}
    all_subs = [text[i: y] for i in range(len(text)) for y in range(i + 1, len(text) + 1)]
    for el in all_subs:
        if el not in d and text.count(el) > 1:
            d[el] = text.count(el)

    return len(d) #замените return len(d) на return d, чтобы посмотреть словарь из повторов

print(duplicate_count(a))
```

Comment: `cbadbaba
{'b': 3, 'a': 3} `

Comment: @Forer а ничего, что для  'cabab' функция возвращает {'a': 2, 'b': 2}

Comment: Извините, температура в голову ударяет, исправляю.